# set axes containing % automatically with plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I wrote a code that returns a scatter chart, but when I use plot I can't set axis properly, instead of have a lower and upper well-defined, they don't have a pattern when inputted in the chart.

How could i set this to occur automatically, because my data come from a callback in dash plotly.

```
 my_dict = {'A': {67: '4.50%', 97: '3.90%', 167: '4.56%', 175: '3.16%'},
'B': {67: '8.15%', 97: '-2.64%', 167: '26.39%', 175: '6.33%'}, 
'C': {67: '7.34%', 97: '-7.60%', 167: '23.68%', 175: '-2.38%'}, 
'D': {67: '49.96%', 97: '9.65%', 167: '68.35%', 175: '83.82%'}, 
'E': {67: '61.73%', 97: '46.97%', 167: '96.78%', 175: '0.00%'}, 
'F': {67: '549.85%', 97: '242.83%', 167: '544.19%', 175: '68.30%'}, 
'G': {67: '22.65%', 97: '17.59%', 167: '19.39%', 175: '23.65%'},
'H': {67: nan, 97: nan, 167: nan, 175: nan}}




fig_2 = px.scatter(df_for_cleaned_chart, x = df['A'], y = df['B'])
```

Then I plot I receive this:

[image]

my actual version that aren't working is this

```
x_sorted = list(df_for_cleaned_chart['A'].values()) #converting data values from a dict to list
    x_min = min(x_sorted) #selecting min value
    x_min = float(x_min.translate({ord('%'): None})) #removing '%' symbol to convert values from str to float
    print(type(x_min)) #confirming if value is a flot = TRUE
    x_max = max(x_sorted) #REPEAT
    x_max = float(x_max.translate({ord('%'): None})) #REPEAT
    print(type(x_max)) #REPEAT

fig_2 = px.scatter(df_for_cleaned_chart, x = A, y = B, range_x= [x_min, x_max])

        #fig_2.update_xaxes(range=[x_min, x_max])  #<----- set automatically the range of x-axis ###### IT ALSO DIDN'T WORK
```

That's the chart generated by this code. It doesn't have a pattern, only plot values following the order of my list

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your question, could you please clarify more? Because the axes are set automatically in plotly if you don't customize them?

Comment: If you look to my x axis, my first value has as minimun value -0.12% and biggest 8.55%, i just want that my scale follow these numbers, same with y value.

I tried use range_x and range_y, but dont work pretty well. i wanna look a dispersion not a 45º line.

Comment: You can control easily the range of the axes. I can understand your problem with range of x and y axes, right? And the ranges change based on the data, and you want the axes set automatically by these ranges, right?

Comment: exactly, cause my variables of chart will be affected by other variables.

Comment: You should add a sample of your data to the question be able to replicate your work and help you. You can do it by `df. head(10).to_dict()` and copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Based on the data in the question, there is no ‰, why did you add a line in your code to remove the percentage sign?

Comment: I write my original dict. I was reading and i believe that my data are being ploted this way out of order because they aren't float's or integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

- Remove the `%` from all cells in the dataframe to be ready for the next step.
- Convert all columns to `float` instead of `string`.
- Customize automatically the ranges based on the `min` and `max` values of each column.
- Add the `%` to the axes to be consistent with the format of the data in the dataframe.

**Full code**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd 
from numpy import nan


my_dict = {'A': {67: '4.50%', 97: '3.90%', 167: '4.56%', 175: '3.16%'},
'B': {67: '8.15%', 97: '-2.64%', 167: '26.39%', 175: '6.33%'}, 
'C': {67: '7.34%', 97: '-7.60%', 167: '23.68%', 175: '-2.38%'}, 
'D': {67: '49.96%', 97: '9.65%', 167: '68.35%', 175: '83.82%'}, 
'E': {67: '61.73%', 97: '46.97%', 167: '96.78%', 175: '0.00%'}, 
'F': {67: '549.85%', 97: '242.83%', 167: '544.19%', 175: '68.30%'}, 
'G': {67: '22.65%', 97: '17.59%', 167: '19.39%', 175: '23.65%'},
'H': {67: nan, 97: nan, 167: nan, 175: nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)

df = df.replace('%','', regex=True)

cols = df.columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')


fig = px.scatter(df, x = df['A'], y = df['B'])

fig.update_xaxes(range=[df['A'].min(), df['A'].max()])  #<----- set automatically the range of x-axis
fig.update_yaxes(range=[df['B'].min(), df['B'].max()])  #<----- set automatically the range of y-axis

fig.update_layout(xaxis_ticksuffix = '%', yaxis_ticksuffix='%')
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image]